# Switching scenes in JavaFX dynamically

Tags: javafx

I want to switch between 2 different scenes:

Scene 1: ScrollPane where I load different images.

Scene 2: the stage is transparent and there's only 1 button to return to Scene 1.

I´ve been able to do it just having a different fxml for each scene and creating a new scene every time I switch them.

The problem is when I switch from scene 2 to scene 1, all the images loaded in scene 1 aren't there (It´s obvious as I´m creating a new scene rather than "loading" Scene1.

Is there any way to keep the images already loaded when I swith from Scene 2 to Scene 1?

Scene1

```
public class ControllerImpl implements Initializable, ControlledScreen {
ScreensController myController;
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
}
public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent){
    myController = screenParent;
}
@FXML
private void goToScreen2(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{
    try {
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage) hideStage.getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/arrow.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@FXML
public javafx.scene.control.Button hideStage;
```

}

Scene2:

```
public class ControllerArrow implements Initializable{

ScreensController myController;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
}

public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent){
    myController = screenParent;
}

@FXML
public javafx.scene.control.Button showStage;

@FXML
private void goToScreen1(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{

    try{

        Stage stage = (Stage) showStage.getScene().getWindow();

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the scene of your stage like:

```
Stage stage = (Stage) scene.getWindow();
stage.setScene(yourScene);
```

So when you have an instance of your scene, you can apply it to your stage

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I select the previous scene? I´ve got 2 different controllers. Do I have to define the scenes in the main?

Comment: How do instantiate your scenes? A complete code example would be helpful.

Comment: Store your scene in ScreensController and get it back in goToScreen(). Now you can apply it to your stage.(Whats the purpose of ScreensController, if it's not used for that?)

Comment: ScreensController was a method I tried to implement to switching scenes but it didn´t work. I´m sorry I´m not really good at java. Can I ask you how I can store the scene in the ScreensController class and get it back? Many thanks.